# meaning of a question with the word "how" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from [Crash Course Biology](https://youtu.be/8kK2zwjRV0M?t=9m23s). It is at around 9 minute and 23 second. Here it is:

> So, **how** is a teenage boy like the enzyme Helicase? They both want to unzip your genes.

I cannot get the question because the answer of the host does not seem to fit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment OP asks *But why is there "is" instead of "does". I cannot get the grammar.*

A catfish is like a cat.
-- How is a catfish like a cat?
They both have whiskers.  In that regard they are alike.

This is not the verb **like** but the **like** that is used to state a comparison, whose meaning is "resembling (something)" or "having features or characteristics similar to (those of something)".

> They heard a high-pitched sound like the sound of a whistle.

Answer (score 0):

*How* is used in the usual sense to form a question.

The answer is word play. The enzymes figuratively "unzip" genes. He says it unwinds the double helix at breakneck speed. Teenage boys are sexually active. In order to have sex, they unzip (= open the zipper of) your *jeans* (which sounds like *genes*).

Comment: But why is there "is" instead of "does". I cannot get the grammar.

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope How would you phrase it with *does*? There is no action.

Comment: I thought the word "like" was used as a verb there

Comment: @DmytroO'Hope Please try to provide more details in your post. I was genuinely convinced your problem was with the word play. It wasn't clear to me that your issue was with "is" and "like". "Like" was not used as verb, so it doesn't require the verb _do_.